# SurfaceView and adding and deleting other views

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I am trying to create a simple game based on the 2D game framework as described in the 2011 Apress book, "Beginning Android Games" by Mario Zechner. Maybe that helps, maybe it doesn't, but either way:

I only have one activity for the whole game. Everything is rendered onto a bitmap, which is then sent to a SurfaceView, and what is sent to the SurfaceView will change based on what screen the game is on.

I want to implement a simple highscore system that lets users enter their name into an EditView on the main menu screen. I've been able to combine the SurfaceView and the EditView with a RelativeLayout, but the problem is getting rid of the EditView once the user moves past the main menu screen.

There is much more to this class, but here's a snipet of what I feel is important:

```
    public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game{
      public EditText et;
      public RelativeLayout rl;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        et = new EditText(this);
        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);

        rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rl.addView(renderView);
        rl.addView(et);
        setContentView(rl);
      }
    }
```

The above is the only activity for the game. The AndroidFastRenderView class extends SurfaceView. The problem I'm having is that while I need the SurfaceView to persist through the whole game, I need EditText to only persist for a short while, then disappear based on touch events.

I try to call RelativeLayout.removeView(et) from my class MainMenuScreen, which is responsible for constructing the bitmap sent to the SurfaceView as well as listening for touch events. But I get an uncaught exception that says I can't edit views that are defined in one thread from another.

I'm sorry for the novel, but I've been trying to solve this myself for hours with no luck. I feel like this is a very simple thing I'm just not getting. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I think only UI Thread can Add and delete views. Try to call the Thread like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        /* STUFF To do in Thread */
        //Delete the view...
        rl.removeView(et);
}});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Are you saying I make that a method in my Activity? I need to remove that view based on events that happen in my SurfaceView Thread. Sorry, I'm just basically super new to all this.

Comment: As I can see in the 

    renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);

You can access from the view to the Activity, so it may be easy to call that function on Surfaceview Thread. (Something like theActivity.runOnUiThread...).

You can also make a whole function inside the Activity class and call that func from the SurfaceView Thread.

Hope I explain it correctly :)